# Как вывести из таблицы данные и их присутствие или отсутствие в другой таблице

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется 2 таблицы:

**favorite:**

```
id | productId | user_id         
1    22          1
2    865         1       
3    27          1
4    12          1
....
```

и **products:**

```
id | productId | name
1    22          Cat
2    865         Dog     
3    27          Frog
4    12          Chicken
....
```

Как вывести все `productId` из `favorite` по `user_id = N` c полем exits 1/0 означающим наличие  `productId` из `favorite` в таблице `products`.

Пробовал что то вроде:

```
SELECT
       tb1.productId,
       IF(tb1.productId  = tb2.productId, 1, 0) as exits
FROM
      `favorite` tb1,
      `products` tb2
WHERE tb1.user = '1'
```

но так выводит очень много раз одни и те же записи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT f.productId, p.productId IS NOT NULL `exists`
FROM favorite f
LEFT JOIN products p USING (productId)
WHERE f.user_id = N
```